# AG-Grid getDataAsCsv function returning error

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using AG-Grid and trying to export my grid data as CSV using getDataAsCsv() when using exportDataAsCsv() this does work but downloads the file rather than return the CSV as a string. According to the AG-Grid docs for JavaScript I believe this should work in the code I have below, however I am getting this error, both when running getDataAsCsv from the console and as part of the function:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'gridOptions.api.getDataAsCsv')
```

and from the code:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...gridOptions.api.getDataAsCsv(params)
    .then...')
```

Here is the full code:

```
document.getElementById('submit-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const params = {
    fileName: 'data.csv',
    skipHeader: false,
    skipFooters: true,
    skipGroups: true,
    columnSeparator: ','
  };

  gridOptions.api.getDataAsCsv(params)
    .then(csv => {
      fetch('/path/to/your/endpoint', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: csv,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        }
      }).then(response => {
        // Handle the response from the server
      }).catch(error => {
        // Handle any errors that occur during the request
      });
    });
});
```

Some additional information, I am using the community version of AG-Grid, version 29.3.3 from the CDN

edit: added both errors, one run from console and one from the code provided

Comment: As far as I can see, `getDataAsCsv` doesn't return a promise, so don't use `.then()` with it. `let csv = ...getDataAsCsv(); console.log(csv); fetch(... { body: csv, ... } ...)`. Look at any of the examples here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/csv-export/